# On compositions of Injective functions and left/right inverse

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I know that this is probably a very basic question, however I would like to have some clarification on writing it as strictly as possible

$$X \neq \varnothing, f : X\rightarrow X$$

Let's define $$f^{0}=id_{X}, f^{n}=f\circ f^{n-1}$$

(1) Prove that the following facts (a),(b),(c) are equivalent:

(a) $$f \: is \: injective$$
(b)$$ \exists \:i\geq 1,t.c.\; f^{i} \: is \: injective$$

(c)$$f^{i} \: is \: injective\: \forall \:i\geq 1$$

(2) Prove that if exist $$i\geq 1\:t.c. \:f^{i}=id_{X} \: than \: f \: is \: invertible$$

(3) Prove that exist a unique injective function $$f \: t.c. \: f^{2}=f \: is \: the \: identity \: functions$$

(4)Show a different function other than identity t.c $$f^{2} = f \: is \: the \: Identity \: function $$

(5)Either f a function injective but not surjective. Prove that if $$f^{n} =f^{m} \: than \: n=m$$

I know that it's a lot of question, but i hope that someone can help me to understand :)

P.S: this is my 1st post here, i hope i haven't broken any rules

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please include what you have tried.

Comment: What does "t.c." mean?

Comment: oh sorry, it means such that

Comment: @Max0815 i worked through the idea that a composition of injective functions is always injective

Comment: Then could you add your work to the question itself with the ‘edit’ tool?